# In Yii how to i enable the CFileLogRoute log tracing and write that log to disc?

Tags: debugging, logging

In Yii how to i enable the CFileLogRoute log tracing and write that log to disc? I want a specific example how to setup the config! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following in your app.config , to write to disc, make sure that the logFile parameter is set to a valid file name such as the one below "sql.log"

Hope this helps!!

```
'log'=>array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter',
    'routes'=>array(
        array(
           'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'trace',
            'categories'=>'system.db.*',
            'logFile'=>'sql.log',
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'error, warning, trace, profile, info',
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            'levels'=>'trace',
            'categories'=>'system.db.*',
        ),
    ),
),
```